# Setting limited number of reviews on product page in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Is is it possible to set a limited number of reviews to display on the product page under the review tab?

Currently some of my products have 40 reviews and to display them all on a single page takes up too much space. Is there a way to limit the number of reviews to say 3, and add a see more link or a pagination link to the review tab?

If this can be done through the functions.php or one of the woocommerce source files that would be great!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network (http://webapps.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I figured out the solution for anyone who is having this problem. You need to edit the comment settings via Wordpress.

Go to **Settings > Discussion** from the Wordpress dashboard. Then under "**Other comment Settings**" check the box that says "**Break comments into pages with [number]....**"

What ever you set the **[number]** as is how many reviews will show on the review tab. The rest get paginated.