# Wordpress pagination different on mobile and desktop

Tags: wordpress, mobile, pagination

Is it possible to use the default Wordpress pagination but have different numbers on mobile and desktop?
For example, I would like to show only 3 reviews per page on mobile and 5 on desktop.

The way to do this for all devices was described in this post:

[Setting limited number of reviews on product page in WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40792214/setting-limited-number-of-reviews-on-product-page-in-woocommerce)

However, that does it for every device.

Answer (score 0):

[wp_is_mobile()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_is_mobile/) is a method that test if the current user browser runs on any mobile device.

To change the number of reviews (or posts) per page, you should set the parameter `posts_per_page` in the main query.

You can do so by adding the following code into the `functions.php` file:

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'change_posts_per_page' );
function change_posts_per_page( $query ) {
    if( !$query->is_main_query() || is_admin() ) return;

    $posts_per_page = wp_is_mobile() ? 3 : 5;
    $query->set( 'posts_per_page', $posts_per_page );
    return;
}
```